# Twitter Unfollow Function

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to start a script in my chrome browser that allows me to unfollow people on my Twitter account. I have the following script but unfortunately it does not work:

```
$('.ProfileCard-content').each(function() {
  var status = $(this).find('.FollowStatus').text();
  var unfollowButton = $(this).find('.useractions-follow-button');
  if (status != 'follows you') {
    unfollowButton.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you debug and see what is not working. `console.log()` is your friend here. `console.log(status); console.log(unfollowButton); console.log(status != 'follows you');`

Comment: Does it work for you? I cant see any error messages...

Comment: I did not run it... Did you add the console lines? Does it have the text? Does it find the button? Is the text a match?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. It says: VM2205:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: unfollowButton is not defined